# Google Translate: Translating back to english mis-translates the original word

Tags: javascript, google-translate

I am using Google Web Translate for translating my webpage to other languages. I have a word "View Dues" on my page. 
When I translate it to any other language, it correctly translates the words.

However, when I select the English language again, the word "**View Dues**" translates to "**View Two**"

It is not a translation mistake. It translates correctly from English to say Arabic. But when I change the language from the google translate dropdown back to English, then it replaces 'View Dues' with 'View Two' instead of keeping the original word as it is

I tried to set page language to 'en', but still, it mistranslates the word.

Answer (score 1):

This is unfortunately just Google translate.

It is good practice to not just simply rely on google translate. Try finding a native speaker of the language you are translating to and let them proof read your pages.

Comment: It is not a translation mistake. It translates correctly from English to say Arabic. But when I change the language from the google translate dropdown back to English, then it replaces 'View Dues' with 'View Two' instead of keeping the original word as it is

Comment: Hmm I see. I still think this is a mistake on the Google side of things